# PHP preg_match gives wrong values

Tags: php, csv, preg-match, explode

I built a csv file with php and try to get data of the years 2013, 2014, 2015 and structure them later on.

I used preg match but that still does give me all years from the file.

Code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table 1`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $print2013 = "";
    $print2014 = "";
    $print2015 = "";

    $explode = explode("\r\n", $row['COL 19']);

    foreach ($explode as $key => $value19b)
    {
        if(preg_match('/2013/', $value19b))
        {
            $print2013 .= "\"$value19b\r\n\"";
        }

        if(preg_match('/2014/', $value19b))
        {
            $print2014 .= "\"$value19b\r\n\"";
        }

        if(preg_match('/2015/', $value19b))
        {
            $print2015 .= "\"$value19b\r\n\"";
        }

        echo $print2013;
        echo $print2014;
        echo $print2015;
    }
}
```

This should save inside of the variable $print2013 all 2013's of the database, but I also get 2014 and 2015 for that variable (for the other ones too)

Example of what I get if I echo:

```
[COL 19] => 14.12.2014 sent mail
6.11.13: control
26.6.2015 blabla
...
```

Does anyone know why this is happening.

Comment: What is the content of `$row['COL 19']`?

Comment: $row numbers stands for the columns of the csv I take the data of

Comment: $row numbers are rows of the csv file in which the data stands on, in this case $row['COL 19'] has values like 2013 went to churche or 2014 went to school and so on

Comment: Sure, but edit your question and add some examples.

Comment: You don't need to use `preg_match` to search a literal string, `strpos` does the same thing faster. `mysql_` functions are now obsolete since several php versions, you should use `mysqli` functions or PDO. About your approach, if I were you, I will use the SQL query to make the largest part of the work.

Comment: Why not just simply filter the data you get with sql? You coud simply use `Where [column with date in it] is Like '%2013%'` And so on.